# Firebase Firestore OR query (Android Studio)

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I've been trying to find a query for almost 2 days now
I want to search id (current user id) from the document 4 fields (customer1,customer2,customer3,customer4)
Here is the firestore document picture 
[image]

tried this query

```
final Query userQuery = collectionReference
                .whereEqualTo("customer1",firebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid())
                .whereEqualTo("customer2",firebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid())
                .whereEqualTo("customer3",firebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid())
                .whereEqualTo("customer4",firebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid());
```

but this only shows up if the current ID is present in all 4. Is there any easier way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that by using a field that is an array containing the uids you want to test, and then applying `array-contains` on it. In your case:

In your case:

```
customer: [customer1, customer2, customer3, customer4]

collectionReference
.where("customer ", "array-contains", firebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid())
```

Comment: but wouldn't that only search it for that particular document? 
e.g final Query userQuery = collectionReference
                .whereEqualTo("customer1",firebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid())
would check all the document and whereever it matches it will show up
For customer: [customer1, customer2, customer3, customer4] wouldn't that just do it for the particular document?

Comment: This query will search all documents in the given collection whose field "customer" is an array containing the uid in parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Firestore does not support logical OR queries among mulitple fields.  So, what you're trying to do is not possible with a single query using the database structure you have now.  You would have to perform multiple queries and merge the results in the client.

If you want to be able to use a single query, you will have to change your database.  One option is to put all the customers into a single array field and use an [array-contains](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#in_and_array-contains-any) query to find a customer in that field.